# Retrieve values from list item when there are varying layouts in the list

Tags: android

I have a listview containing different xml layouts, each with different views. I was wondering how I can get the data from the views inside the item that the user has clicked on, inside the `onItemClick` method.

My listview is made up of multiple layouts so I cannot know for sure which layout is being pressed when the onItemClick method is called. For example, one of the items in the layouts in the listview is:

```
// list_item.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where as another layout in the listview could be:

```
// list_item_name.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="28sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I am at a loss as to how to get the data for all these views for any layout within the listview.

My previous attempt was this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {            
    Object obj = adapter.getItem(position);
    String value = obj.toString();
}
```

However `value` in this instance, returns a string containing all the values of all the views inside this item, for example: `{caption=MobileNumber, value=07000123456}` <<< I cannot do anything with this string unless I try and pick it apart using `substring`, which is unreliable at best considering the values may have been created by the user.

This is my adapter in use (credit to [Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/), I did not create this adapter):

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();  
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;  
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;  

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {  
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);  
    }  

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  
        this.headers.add(section);  
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);  
    }
    public void addSectionNoHeader(String section, Adapter adapter) {
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return section;  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getViewTypeCount() {  
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections  
        int total = 1;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
        int type = 1;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;  
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {  
        return false;  
    }  

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {  
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        int sectionnum = 0;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            sectionnum++;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  

}
```

I'm looking for a way of extracting the values of *all* the views inside the item. But the fact that the item that has been clicked could be one of any layouts is confusing me. Any ideas?

Here is an example of how I am using this adapter in code:

```
SeparatedListAdapter adapter;
Customer cust;
ListView lvDetails;

public Map<String,?> createDoubleItem(String title, String caption) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_VALUE, title);  
        item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);  
        return item;  
    }

    public Map<String,?> createSingleItem(String name) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_VALUE, name);
        return item;
    } 

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_customer);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        cust = Db.Functions.getCustomer(intent.getStringExtra("uuid"));
        lvDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custdetails);
        adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
        lvDetails.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Gen.popup("Item clicked");
            }
        });

        // Name
        List<Map<String,?>> name = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
        if (cust.firstName == null && cust.lastName == null)
            name.add(createSingleItem("Unnamed Customer"));
        else
            name.add(createSingleItem(
                    ((cust.title != null) ? cust.title + " " : "") +
                    ((cust.firstName != null) ? cust.firstName + " " : "") +
                    ((cust.lastName != null) ? cust.lastName : "")));
        adapter.addSection("Name", new SimpleAdapter(this, name, R.layout.list_item_name,   
                new String[] { ITEM_VALUE },
                new int[] { R.id.lblName }));
        // Phones
        if ((cust.mobileNumber != null || cust.homeNumber != null || cust.workNumber != null) && SHOW_PHONES)
        {
            List<Map<String,?>> phone = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
            if (cust.mobileNumber != null)
                phone.add(createDoubleItem(cust.mobileNumber, "Mobile"));
            if (cust.homeNumber != null)
                phone.add(createDoubleItem(cust.homeNumber, "Home"));
            if (cust.workNumber != null)
                phone.add(createDoubleItem(cust.workNumber, "Work"));
            adapter.addSection("Phone", new SimpleAdapter(this, phone, R.layout.list_item,   
                    new String[] { ITEM_VALUE, ITEM_CAPTION },
                    new int[] { R.id.lblSub, R.id.lblMain }));
        }  
        lvDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: your get the data from your adapter or your model, not from your views.

Comment: your adapter returns either a String (your sections.keySet is a set of Strings) or an Adapter (in which case you can fetch a specific item by getItem on it again)

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for the clarification, I'm afraid I'm still (quite apparently) new to android development, would you be able to give me an example in the form of an answer?

Comment: Well, you can do this by setting onCLickListeners programmatically, but it's easier to do it like the above (in case you have layout files). If not, then you can always set listeners everywhere :)

Comment: Well I used to do C# but I am a *complete* newbie at android development, so could really use an example if anyone can provide one! Else I am just going in blind, and can't find much else on the internet about advanced listviews like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way - paste this into each of the xml Views:

```
android:onClick="someFunction"
```

Then inside this `someFunction` do:

```
public void someFunction(View v){

switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.lblSub:
  // This layout was clicked, do something about it
  break;

case R.id.lblMain:
  // This layout was clicked, do something about it
  break;

}
```

Comment: A very interesting method - I will try this now. Am I correct in assuming this only triggers if you press on the views themselves, but **not** the entire list item?

Comment: Yes, this works on the concrete view only, however, i think that you can put this in the listView too and put its id in a case, but then I don't know which click might get caught, maybe the inner one.

Comment: Is there an alternative way of doing this so I know which *list item* was pressed (and consequently which layout it is using), instead of which view?

Comment: I decided to try putting `onClick="function"` in each layout's top-level view (in this case, the `RelativeLayout` which contained the two textviews) - and it worked perfectly. I just add different `onClick` functions for different layout files, and can call different functions in the code. Fantastic solution!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as ideal as I first thought... :(
Normally my listview provides haptic feedback on the touch event, and also the item row lights up and changes colour. If I use the `onClick` method, then I dont get the colour change or vibration :( Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, in your case I would have set those manually, aren't you doing this color change manualy?

Comment: Well actually now that you mention it - I can do the vibration manually, yes. (My bad). But the colour change is part of the listview scheme assigned in the xml layout file: `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolour"`, so it changes colour automatically. Is there a way of doing it manually?

Comment: Well sure :) Why the hell not ? :-D I think you can set this in the layout as `android:background ="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolour"` or the `android:src` (which is the foreground in this case).

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND! Uhhh I mean, thank you very much. I am very happy XD

Answer (score 1):

My understanding here is that you have 3 types of items:

- Section title (which are disabled thanks to the `areAllItemsSelectable` and `isEnabled` methods and therefore cannot be clicked)
- Single items
- Double items

You also have apparently 2 sections, Name and Phone.

Items from section 1 (`adapter.getItemViewType(position) == 1`) are single items, while section 2 (`adapter.getItemViewType(position) == 2`).

In both cases, your `item` object (`adapter.getItem(position)`) is declared a `Map<String, ?>` and is even defined as a `Map<String, String>`.

That means that you can cast item to a `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> itemAsMap = (Map<String, String>) item;
```

and then fetch your value from the Map, using the `ITEM_VALUE` and `ITEM_CAPTION` keys.